# Why my GoogleAds API PHP example script is failing?

Tags: php, google-api

I am upgrading from googleAdWords API to googleAds API.
I a getting a fatal error:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Google\ApiCore\Transport\Grpc\ServerStreamingCallWrapper::__construct() must be an instance of Grpc\ServerStreamingCall, instance of Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V9\GoogleAdsLoggingServerStreamingCall given, called in /var/www/vendor/google/gax/src/Transport/GrpcTransport.php on line 208 and defined in /var/www/vendor/google/gax/src/Transport/Grpc/ServerStreamingCallWrapper.php:49
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vendor/google/gax/src/Transport/GrpcTransport.php(208): Google\ApiCore\Transport\Grpc\ServerStreamingCallWrapper->__construct()
#1 /var/www/vendor/google/gax/src/GapicClientTrait.php(608): Google\ApiCore\Transport\GrpcTransport->startServerStreamingCall()
#2 /var/www/vendor/google/gax/src/Middleware/CredentialsWrapperMiddleware.php(61): Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V9\Services\Gapic\GoogleAdsServiceGapicClient->Google\ApiCore{closure}()
#3 /var/www/vendor/google/gax/src/Middleware/FixedHeaderMiddleware.php(66): Google\A in /var/www/vendor/google/gax/src/Transport/Grpc/ServerStreamingCallWrapper.php on line 49

The sample example is this:

```
            <?php

        namespace Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\Reporting;

        require_once '/var/www/newVendor/vendor/autoload.php';

        use GetOpt\GetOpt;
        use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\Utils\ArgumentNames;
        use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Examples\Utils\ArgumentParser;
        use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V9\GoogleAdsClient;
        use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V9\GoogleAdsClientBuilder;
        use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V9\GoogleAdsException;
        use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V9\GoogleAdsServerStreamDecorator;
        use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\OAuth2TokenBuilder;
        use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V9\Enums\KeywordMatchTypeEnum\KeywordMatchType;
        use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V9\Errors\GoogleAdsError;
        use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V9\Services\GoogleAdsRow;
        use Google\ApiCore\ApiException;

        /**
         * This example gets keyword performance statistics for the 50 keywords with the most impressions
         * over the last 7 days.
         */
        class GetKeywordStats
        {
            private const CUSTOMER_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

            public static function main()
            {
                // Either pass the required parameters for this example on the command line, or insert them
                // into the constants above.
                $options = (new ArgumentParser())->parseCommandArguments([
                    ArgumentNames::CUSTOMER_ID => GetOpt::REQUIRED_ARGUMENT
                ]);

                // Generate a refreshable OAuth2 credential for authentication.
                $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())->fromFile('/var/www/google_ads_php.ini')->build();

                // Construct a Google Ads client configured from a properties file and the
                // OAuth2 credentials above.
                $googleAdsClient = (new GoogleAdsClientBuilder())->fromFile('/var/www/google_ads_php.ini')
                    ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
                    ->build();

                try {
                    self::runExample(
                        $googleAdsClient,
                        $options[ArgumentNames::CUSTOMER_ID] ?: self::CUSTOMER_ID
                    );
                } catch (GoogleAdsException $googleAdsException) {
                    printf(
                        "Request with ID '%s' has failed.%sGoogle Ads failure details:%s",
                        $googleAdsException->getRequestId(),
                        PHP_EOL,
                        PHP_EOL
                    );
                    foreach ($googleAdsException->getGoogleAdsFailure()->getErrors() as $error) {
                        /** @var GoogleAdsError $error */
                        printf(
                            "\t%s: %s%s",
                            $error->getErrorCode()->getErrorCode(),
                            $error->getMessage(),
                            PHP_EOL
                        );
                    }
                    exit(1);
                } catch (ApiException $apiException) {
                    printf(
                        "ApiException was thrown with message '%s'.%s",
                        $apiException->getMessage(),
                        PHP_EOL
                    );
                    exit(1);
                }
            }

            /**
             * Runs the example.
             *
             * @param GoogleAdsClient $googleAdsClient the Google Ads API client
             * @param int $customerId the customer ID
             */
            // [START get_keyword_stats]
            public static function runExample(GoogleAdsClient $googleAdsClient, int $customerId)
            {
                $googleAdsServiceClient = $googleAdsClient->getGoogleAdsServiceClient();
                // Creates a query that retrieves all keyword statistics.
                $query =
                    "SELECT campaign.id, "
                        . "campaign.name, "
                        . "ad_group.id, "
                        . "ad_group.name, "
                        . "ad_group_criterion.criterion_id, "
                        . "ad_group_criterion.keyword.text, "
                        . "ad_group_criterion.keyword.match_type, "
                        . "metrics.impressions, "
                        . "metrics.clicks, "
                        . "metrics.cost_micros "
                    . "FROM keyword_view "
                    . "WHERE segments.date DURING LAST_7_DAYS "
                        . "AND campaign.advertising_channel_type = 'SEARCH' "
                        . "AND ad_group.status = 'ENABLED' "
                        . "AND ad_group_criterion.status IN ('ENABLED', 'PAUSED') "
                    . "ORDER BY metrics.impressions DESC "
                    . "LIMIT 10";

                // Issues a search stream request.
                /** @var GoogleAdsServerStreamDecorator $stream */
                $stream =
                    $googleAdsServiceClient->searchStream($customerId, $query);

                // Iterates over all rows in all messages and prints the requested field values for
                // the keyword in each row.
                foreach ($stream->iterateAllElements() as $googleAdsRow) {
                    /** @var GoogleAdsRow $googleAdsRow */
                    $campaign = $googleAdsRow->getCampaign();
                    $adGroup = $googleAdsRow->getAdGroup();
                    $adGroupCriterion = $googleAdsRow->getAdGroupCriterion();
                    $metrics = $googleAdsRow->getMetrics();
                    printf(
                        "Keyword text '%s' with "
                        . "match type %s "
                        . "and ID %d "
                        . "in ad group '%s' "
                        . "with ID %d "
                        . "in campaign '%s' "
                        . "with ID %d "
                        . "had %d impression(s), "
                        . "%d click(s), "
                        . "and %d cost (in micros) "
                        . "during the last 7 days.%s",
                        $adGroupCriterion->getKeyword()->getText(),
                        KeywordMatchType::name($adGroupCriterion->getKeyword()->getMatchType()),
                        $adGroupCriterion->getCriterionId(),
                        $adGroup->getName(),
                        $adGroup->getId(),
                        $campaign->getName(),
                        $campaign->getId(),
                        $metrics->getImpressions(),
                        $metrics->getClicks(),
                        $metrics->getCostMicros(),
                        PHP_EOL
                    );
                }
            }
            // [END get_keyword_stats]
        }

        GetKeywordStats::main();
```

I had installed Grpc extension in PHP following this link:

https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc

What could be?

Thanks